# Denary to Binary converter comes with no output

Tags: python

In my denary to binary converter it seems to take in the users input and work out if it needs to add 0's or 1's. But it doesnt come out with any output at the end.

```
def converter(denarynumber):
    binarylist = []
    while (denarynumber > 0):
        if denarynumber % 2 > 0:
            binarylist.append(1)
        elif denarynumber % 2 == 0:
            binarylist.append(0)
        denarynumber // 2
        denarynumber = int(denarynumber)
    print(binarylist[::-1])
def main():
    print("This is a dec. to bin. converter")
    denarynumber = int(input("Please enter your denary number:"))
    converter(denarynumber)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside yout while loop you are dividing `denarynumber` but you are not updating its value, causing an infinite loop

Try changing

```
denarynumber // 2
```

to

```
denarynumber = denarynumber // 2
```

Comment: or even better `denarynumber //= 2`

Comment: Thank you this works. I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane to be honest i didn't know this was possible lol, thought it was delimited to one character operations only. Learning everyday!

Comment: you're learning fast : You're already faster at typing good answers than I !